# Text-overflow ellipsis in <ion-card-title> does not work --> Shadow-Dom-Element does not take parent width

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a problem with a List Page in **Ionic 4**.
I want to display some `<ion-card>` elements.
The texts in  can be very long (they are comming from the backend). I do not want them to line break, but to use the ellisis ("...") - See Screenshots below.

Normally I would just set `overflow: hidden` on the parent, and `white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;` on the element I want to have the ellipsis. However because of the web-component-shadow-dom-stuff this does not work out of the box, and I can't figure out why...

You can see, that `<ion-card-title>` is not taking the width of the parent. **How do I manipulate the text "This is a long text. Lorem..." that it fits the container and correctly sets the ellipsis?**

[image]

**HTML**

```
   <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
        <div class="card-header-title-wrapper">
            <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
            <ion-card-title>This is a long text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
                tempor</ion-card-title>
        </div>
        <ion-card-subtitle text-end>Subtitle</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
        Card Content...
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

**(simplified) CSS**

```
div.card-header-title-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;

  ion-checkbox {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}

ion-card-header {
    ion-card-title {
        font-size: 16px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
}
```

### It currently looks like this

[image]

### I want it to look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `ion-card-title` css, add `overflow: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

just adding `overflow: hidden` did not seem to work.

following this from csstricks, `width` is required on the element:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

```css
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

adding a width fixed it for me...